# How to extract ec2 instance details like name, memory from aws website using python selenium

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to extract the ec2 instance names from https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/ using python selenium.
I have tried following methods:

1. `find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/awsui-table/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr")`
2. `tbl_rows = drv.find_elements_by_class_name("awsui-table-row")`

Both of the methods return empty results. How can I fix this?
Below sample code returns zero rows

```
url = "https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/"
drv = webdriver.Chrome("some path")
drv.get(url)
sleep(3)
drv.maximize_window()
sleep(1)
tbl_rows = drv.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='awsui-table-row']")
pr("number of rows in table: {}".format(len(tbl_rows)))
```

Comment: Do you know about the console mode? For instance, in Chrome press F12 to change to deveoper mode and go to console. You can now enter any xpath expression as $x("xpath expression") and this will list up the elements that are found. For your xpath above, this will return an empty list.

Comment: It works in console mode. When I enter the xpath in console mode, it properly points to the correct web element. But when I use the same xpath in code, it returns empty value

Comment: Well, I have problems to believe that. Definitely, the xpath above will not work in Chromium console, as you have nested ". Even fixing this, the result is empty for me, using the web site you mentioned.

Comment: Could you try the following xpath once: "//tr[@class='awsui-table-row']"

Comment: @user2622678 what element are you looking for? what do you mean by ec2? I see both locators you presented in the question matching 20 elements

Comment: Andreas, I tried teh following 
        tbl_rows = drv.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='awsui-table-row']")
        print("number of rows in table: {}".format(len(tbl_rows)))
Here is the output:
********** ('number of rows in table: 0',) **********

Comment: Eliyahu, I mean I am trying to get name of the ec2 instances available in a region - like t3.nano etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the instance table was inside iframe. I can fetch table rows after including the following statements in the script:

```
iframe = drv.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iFrameResizer0"]')
drv.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```